# How to get a specific array of object of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Say I have an object:

```
"changes": {
  "attr1" : [
    "sub_attr1": false,
    "sub_attr2": true,
    ...
  ],
  "attr2" : [
    "sub_attr1": false,
    "sub_attr2": true,
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

I want to extract an specific attr of the `changes` object to a new one. Lets say I want to extract `attr1`.

```
"new_obj" : [
  "sub_attr1": false,
  "sub_attr2": true,
  ...
]
```

and

```
"changes": {
  "attr2" : [
    "sub_attr1": false,
    "sub_attr2": true,
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

How may I achieve this?

Comment: Filter out everything else and save.

Comment: `object2.new_obj = object.changes.attr1`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work.

```
const extract = (obj, keyToExtract) => {

    const entries = Object.entries(obj);
    
    const entry = entries.find(([key, value]) => key === keyToExtract);
    if(entry) {
        delete obj[keyToExtract]
        return {
            "new_obj": entry[1]
        }
    }
    
}

extract(obj.changes, "attr1")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Se changes é um objeto então você pode buscar os filhos dele assim
changes.filho (objeto)

Sendo array:
changes['filho'] (array)

Comment: Post in English, please.